# MySQL remove duplicates based on 2 or more keys in a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, session, duplicates

Here is the basic scenario.

I am trying to calculate the number of items a user adds to a cart during a certain session. A single user can have multiple carts and multiple sessions. However, what I am seeing is that the same `product_id` is added twice (by mistake) during the same `session` in the same `cart`.

It can surely be the case that the same product is added to different carts on different sessions by the same user. Since session_id and cart_id have an injective (1-1) relationship, we cannot have the same `product_id` added twice.

How can I remove duplicates of `product_id` in a single `cart` on a single `session`? **Note that the SCANS are counted when** `action_name = ADD`. So there is a dependency

Please note, this table is generated by a `JOIN` command, so the duplicate removal should take place during the code.

Here is the code and the table

```
SELECT   u.userId
    ,c.session_id
    ,c.cartId
    ,i.product_Id
    ,i.action_name

    ,u.emailAddress
    ,COUNT(IF(i.action_name = 'ADD', 1, NULL)) AS SCANS
FROM User_ AS u
INNER JOIN carts AS c ON c.userId = u.userId
INNER JOIN Impressions AS i ON i.session_id = c.session_id
WHERE i.createDate >= '2014-06-18'

    AND i.session_id <> ''
    AND c.cartId NOT IN 
    (SELECT cartId FROM cart_designers WHERE designId=102
    )
ORDER BY u.userId, c.session_id, c.cartId
```

What I saw was that the duplicate `ADD`s in the table below was messing up the `SCANS` count.

```
+---------+------------+---------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+
| user_id | session_id | cart_id | product_id    | action_name | email           |
+---------+------------+---------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1       | 1aaaa      | 1       | 1             | ADD <==problem| first@mail.org  |
| 1       | 1aaaa      | 1       | 1             | ADD <= problem| first@mail.org  |
| 1       | 1aaaa      | 1       | 6             | ADD           | first@mail.org  |
| 1       | 1aaaa      | 4       | 1             | ADD           | first@mail.org  |
| 1       | 1aaaa      | 4       | 6             | ADD <== okay  | first@mail.org  |
| 1       | 1cccc      | 6       | 8             | ADD           | first@mail.org  |
| 2       | 2ffff      | 2       | 5             | SENDMAIL      | second@mail.org |
| 2       | 2ffff      | 2       | 2             | ADD           | second@mail.org |
| 3       | 3bbbb      | 5       | 9             | ADD           | third@mail.org  |
| 3       | 3bbbb      | 5       | 10            | SENDMAIL      | third@mail.org  |
| 3       | 3dddd      | 3       | 3             | SENDMAIL      | third@mail.org  |
| 3       | 3dddd      | 3       | 4             | ADD           | third@mail.org  |
| 3       | 3dddd      | 3       | 7             | REMOVE        | third@mail.org  |
+---------+------------+---------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.userId ,
                c.session_id ,
                c.cartId ,
                i.product_Id ,
                i.action_name ,
                u.emailAddress
FROM User_ AS u
INNER JOIN carts AS c ON c.userId = u.userId
INNER JOIN Impressions AS i ON i.session_id = c.session_id
WHERE i.createDate >= '2014-06-18'
  AND i.session_id <> ''
  AND c.cartId NOT IN
    (SELECT cartId
     FROM cart_designers
     WHERE designId=102 )
ORDER BY u.userId,
         c.session_id,
         c.cartId
```

I guess adding **DISTINCT** would help. It removes all duplicates in a CART for a particular user_id, session_id, product_id, action_name, email_id. From this you can calculate SCANS.

Comment: No I don't think that solves the problem. I need the "duplicates" in there. For other purposes; I just need the duplicate Product ADDs inside a single session/cart removed.